# Android Studio SQLite onUpgrade

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

Hi I'm currently working on a language dictionary app. The database is from SQLite db which I input manually. The feature of the app is users can ask any words that is not on the list to be added, so I have to update the database manually everytime app updated.

The problem is, everytime I change the db data, the list is not updated, when I change the version number, the app crashed.

How can I handle this problem? Tutorials out there only showing how to do it on realtime input or adding columns while main only to add rows and on already existing db. Thank you.

Here is my DataBaseHelper class

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DB_Name = "kamus_db";
    private static final int DB_VER = 1;

    private static final String TB_DATA = "tb_data";
    private static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COL_TURKI = "turki";
    private static final String COL_ISTILAH ="istilah";
    private static final String COL_INDONESIA = "indonesia";

    private static DataBaseHelper dbInstance;
    private static SQLiteDatabase db;

    private  DataBaseHelper(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, DB_Name, null, DB_VER);
    }

    static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {
        if (dbInstance == null) {
            dbInstance = new DataBaseHelper(ctx);
            db = dbInstance.getWritableDatabase();
        } return dbInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        super.close();
        if (dbInstance != null) {
            dbInstance.close();
        }
    }

    List<Kamus> getAllKamus() {
        List<Kamus> kamusList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TB_DATA, new String[] {
                COL_ID, COL_TURKI, COL_ISTILAH, COL_INDONESIA
        }, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() >= 1 ) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            do {
                Kamus kamus = new Kamus();
                kamus.setTurki(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_TURKI)));
                kamus.setIstilah(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_ISTILAH)));
                kamus.setIndonesia(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_INDONESIA)));
                kamusList.add(kamus);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } return kamusList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        String TAG = "TAG";

        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database. Existing contents will be lost. ["
            + oldVersion + "] -> [" + newVersion + "]");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + TB_DATA);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using **SQLiteAssetHelper** you should refer to [ReadMe - Database Upgrades](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/README.markdown#database-upgrades).

You possibly want to look at the **Upgrades via overwrite** section and call the **setForcedUpgrade()** method (***if the users don't update the database***), this will replace the database with the updated database.

If users do update the database, then what needs to be done depends upon what changes have been made. You would likely need to write code that will preserve data if need be.

Comment: Yes I just found SQLiteAssetHelper and tried it. That is really what I want because no user is updating the update but me. Use the setForcedUpgrade() method and increase the db version. But after the Installation the app crash on the first launch, and works on the second one. Any solution for this?

Comment: @Kefen first as this answer helped. Tick this question (if it did in fact help), then ask another including the stacktrace from the log for the exception. If you don't know how to get stack trace (via Log at the bottom) then refer to [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug). The stack-trace tells you what cause the exception (crash) and why. There's a good chance I will see the next question (on going/adding to questions gets disjointed/confusing and not that helpful for the community as a whole).